# How can I write this query in PostgreSQL? Original from Oracle

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT ACTOR_NAME
FROM MOVIES
WHERE MOVIE_NAME = 'Isle of Dogs'
ORDER BY SUBSTR(ACTOR_NAME, INSTR(ACTOR_NAME, ' ', -1)+1) ASC;
```

Comment: Please explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [POSITION](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/position-function.php) command in place of `INSTR`